# Swing add new Component

Tags: java, swing

I need to add dynamicaly Components to JPanel, but if i make just add(Component) then component doesn't appears, if i make then JPanel.revalidate(); then it appears, but JPanel blinks, can I make it more fine, without blinking?

Hm, i have found solution,just after add(component); i have write component.repaint(); and it works, but now there is another Problem with Window resizing, if i resize window then all my added components disapeard!!!

Comment: Are you resizing your component to a smaller or larger size?

Comment: Consider posting a short example that shows the problem: http://sscce.org/

Comment: What LayoutManager do you use? Some LayoutManagers don't support adding components later on; others perform a lot of processing which might explain the blinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic, but you should make sure each component is

1) added from the EDT (see `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`)

2) added only once per instance

Answer (score 0):

Might be a better idea to add the components on initialization and hide them, making them visible when needed.

Use the method `Component.setVisible(boolean b)` so show and hide components.

**Edit:**

I just tried a simple test class where I added random components to the main JFrame and it worked fine.

Try calling `JFrame.pack()` following `JPanel.revalidate()`.

If this does not make a difference could you post some of your code where you add the dynamic components?

**Another Edit:**

Make your main component Implement the `ComponentListener` interface and implement the `componentResized(ComponentEvent e)` method to call JFrame.pack().

Comment: No, because at moment of initialization i don't now which component will be added :(

Answer (score 0):

if you add a new component you have to call `revalidate`.

Example:

```
panel.add(new JButton(...), ...);
panel.revalidate();
```

Make sure you're calling this from within the EDT.

If it still flickers have a look at `panel.setDoubleBuffered`.

Hope that helps, even though example code from your side would be nice to actually see the effect you are describing.